# How Graph Data Science Library use in neo4j desktop?

Tags: neo4j

I use [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/split-relationships/) site to run this query:

```
CALL gds.graph.project(
    'graph',
    'Label',
    { TYPE: { orientation: 'UNDIRECTED' } }
)
```

But it arise this error:

> `gds.graph.project` is unavailable because it is `sandboxed` and has
> dependencies outside of the sandbox. Sandboxing is controlled by the
> dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted setting. Only unrestrict
> procedures you can trust with access to database internals.

How can use gds in neo4j desktop?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add GDS plugin to the Neo4j Desktop by clicking the install button:

[image]